# Regex only match after a certain string

Tags: objective-c, regex, pattern-matching

I am hoping to match multiple names within a document, but only match names after a certain string.

For example, the document:

Name: Tom
Name: Alex
Name: Karina
**Name: Other Names**
Name: Josh
Name: Sarah
Name: Mike

So I want to only match names that are after "Other Names". The intended output would be Josh, Sarah, Mike.

My current pattern: `(?:Other Names)[\s\S]+([A-Za-z]+)`

But it only returns the last name!

Comment: Why not split the input into an array of strings, then use `indexOfObject:` on the array to find the `@"Name: Other Names"` one, and then use `subarrayWithRange:` to get the remainder?

Comment: ah because I need to do it in regex for the project I'm working on :/

Comment: You should show your code so we can see how it is you're matching the input to your regular expression.

Comment: And if "Other Names" doesn't occur? Do you want all of them, or none of them?

Comment: Other names will definitely occur. And I only want the matches after other names. I'll put my code up in a tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved  in Objective C since the regex flavor it supports is ICU (it supports the `\G` operator):

```
(?:Name:\s+Other\s+Names\s*|(?!^)\G\s*)Name:\s+(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW7cF4/1)

The `(?:Name:\s+Other\s+Names\s*|(?!^)\G\s*)` part will find the `Name: Other Names` and `(?!^)\G` will match the end of the previous successful match. `Name:\s+(\w+)` will match `Name:` + whitespace(s) and capture into Group 1 the Name (if it consists of 1 word). If it contains more, just use `.+` instead of `\w+`.

See the [Objective C demo](https://ideone.com/KabV4a):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"(?:Name:\\s+Other\\s+Names\\s*|(?!^)\\G\\s*)Name:\\s+(\\w+)";
NSString *string = @"Name: Tom\nName: Alex\nName: Karina\nName: Other Names\nName: Josh\nName: Sarah\nName: Mike";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"group1: %@", [string substringWithRange:group1]);
}
```

Comment: My regex outputs `Josh`, `Sarah` and `Mike`. Is it what you need?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex (?<=Other Names).*

```
NSString *text = @"Name: Tom Name: Alex Name: Karina Name: Other Names Name: Josh Name: Sarah Name: Mike";

NSString *pattern = @"(?<=Other Names).*";

NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regularExpression firstMatchInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

NSString *output = [text substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to match every name, not just the following string. For example: "josh", "sarah", "mike".

Comment: you want all name in list or all names in one string

Answer (score 0):

```
name: *other *names\s*([a-zA-Z ]+)
```

the above regex will give ypu the exact result what you want. Use ignore case option